# Array.toString() returns array instead of string - Why? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tostring

I've been using a function to turn different strings into snake_case. When I try to use Array.toString() to convert the final array into a string, the function still returns an array. For example, try identify(punctuated). Why is underlinedStringNew an array instead of a string?

Best regards
Beni

```js
let punctuated = ',Hello, World???'

function identify(input) {
  let array = input.split("");
  let smallArray = [];
  let newestArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    smallArray[i] = array[i].toLowerCase();
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == "." && array[i + 1] == ".") {
      return "WtfCase";
    }
  }

  let underlinedString = input.replace(/[^A-z]/g, "_");

  let smallUnderlinedArray = [];
  let capitalizedLetters = [];
  let underlinedArray = underlinedString.split("");
  console.log("Underlined Array: " + underlinedArray);

  for (let i = 0; i < underlinedArray.length; i++) {
    smallUnderlinedArray[i] = underlinedArray[i].toLowerCase();
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < underlinedArray.length; i++) {
    if (underlinedArray[i] !== smallUnderlinedArray[i]) {
      capitalizedLetters.push(i);
    };
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < capitalizedLetters.length; i++) {
    underlinedArray.splice(capitalizedLetters[i], 0, "_");
  }

  let i = 0;
  for (i; i < underlinedArray.length; i++) {
    if (underlinedArray[i] == "_" && underlinedArray[i + 1] == "_") {
      underlinedArray.splice(i, 1);
      i = i - 1;
    };
  };

  if (underlinedArray[underlinedArray.length - 1] == "_") {
    underlinedArray.splice(underlinedArray.length - 1, 1);
  }

  if (underlinedArray[0] == "_") {
    underlinedArray.splice(0, 1);
  }

  let underlinedStringNew = underlinedArray.toString();
  console.log("Should be a string: " + underlinedStringNew);

};
```

Comment: Creates a string in my console... what's your actual output?

Comment: Your output *is* a string... it's just comma separated.

Comment: yeah it's a string, if you do "console.log("Should be a string: " + typeof underlinedStringNew);" it returns a string

Comment: Indeed, when I run this I get a string, just separated by commas.

Comment: Are you looking to return the string without the commas?

Comment: Thanks! I double-checked the ouput with (Array.isArray) and received true. Which led me to think that ouput was an array. However, I'll give it a try again and remove the comas. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking is to join elements of you array without `,`. By default, `join` add `,`. If you want to remove them use an empty string `''`.

```
// note that I simply a bit your code just to showcase the solution.
var a = ',Hello, World???'.replace(/[^A-z]/g, "_").split("").join('');
console.log("Should be a string: " + a);
```

Output:

```
Should be a string: _Hello__World___
```

If you want to learn more about `join`, check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Some examples:

```
var elements = ['Fire', 'Wind', 'Rain'];

console.log(elements.join());
// expected output: Fire,Wind,Rain

console.log(elements.join(''));
// expected output: FireWindRain

console.log(elements.join('-'));
// expected output: Fire-Wind-Rain
```

Comment: @Benisburgers You are welcome. Dont forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

your code should be fine. for example,

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.toString();
```

if you console it, you will see the result like this `Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango`

but if you want replace the commas(,) and replace it with Blank space

suppose,

```
var punctuated = "Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango"
punctuated.split(",").join(" ");
```

the result will be `Banana Orange Apple Mango`

to learn more about replace from string you can follw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)